# Form the route with the endpoints

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

So let's say we are given the endpoints (A, B), (B, C), (C, D), then we can form the route A -> B -> C.

Note that the order the endpoints are given is random. So (A, B), (C, D), (B, C) would also have yielded the route A -> B -> C.

But in general, if we are given ordered pairs of endpoints, how to construct the route?

I'm not sure what data structure is most helpful here. I'm thinking of storing each coordinates (x,y) into a list as the inputs are read in.

So (A, B), (C, D) would be stored as {A, B, C, D}. Whether each element is x or y coordinates can be determined by the parity of its position in the list (so the 1st entry in the list is x, 2nd entry is y, 3rd is x, etc). Then as each ordered pair is read in, we look up the list to see if either the x or y coordinate is already in the list. If so, we connect.

To demonstrate, suppose we are reading in (A, B), (C, D), (B, C), our list would be {A, B, C, D} after (C, D) is just read. When (B, C) is read, we see that B is already in the list. So we know A -> B -> C. Also C is in the list, and we have A-> B -> C -> D, and then we add (B, C) to the list to form {A, B, C, D, B, C}.

My difficult is: how do we store A -> B -> C? What data structure should I use? How do we keep track of the partial route we have formed as we go?

Thank you!

Comment: Spanning tree, maybe?

Comment: If the route is `a_1 -> a_2 -> ... -> a_n`, will the input contain exactly the pairs `(a_i, a_{i + 1})` for every `1 <= i < n`? Will you have extra pairs like `(a_1, a_3)`? If the latter is not the case, just store for every node the successor of it in a hash table or something. So read the pairs `(x, y)` incrementally and set `succ[x] = y` for every pair. Then find the starting point (it's the one that has not appeared as the endpoint in any of the pairs) and reconstruct the path by following pointers.

Comment: If the latter *is* the case, you want to find a [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the acyclic graph induced by the edges `(x, y)`

Comment: Niklas: it doesn't wrap around... so (a_n, a_1) will not be given. But  you do know how many nodes there are (i.e., n is given).

Comment: @user3213711: Yeah, I didn't suggest it would wrap around. I just asked whether for a tour like `A -> B -> C`, you can be given `(A, C)` as an input. Also, your question seems to be a bit unclear. I for one don't know what specifically you are asking. Do you ask about an algorithm that reconstructs the tour? Because the internal data structure and "keeping track" stuff is only an implementation detail.

Comment: Yeah it's an adjacency list.

Comment: This is called a 'topological sort', and the algorithm is given in Knuth volume 1. The Unix utility 'tsort' is an example implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a graph of directed edges with [adjacency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) list representation. Then use [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on start point till end point and store previously visited nodes in buffer and as soon as you reach destination the values in the buffer is the path.

Comment: in case the OP doesn't know it, a "graph" is a fairly standard data structure in programming, I refer him to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: Sorry. I'm really new to graphs. How can I construct the graph from the adjacency list? Thank you!

Comment: @user3213711 If you are new it will be nice if you learn that using a standard text book of datastructures and algorithms like CLRS algorithm book (type in google),